# Асинхронная библиотека для работы с zip архивами

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть ли асинхронная библиотека для работы с .zip файлами.
Интересует создание архива и добавление в него файлов.

Comment: Вся асинхронная работа основана на отдаче времени одному коду, коорый находится в ожидании какого либо ввода-вывода, т.е. не использует процессор. А архиваторы тратят очень много процессора, поэтому практически не годятся в кандидаты для асинхронной работы. Больше вероятность найти что то многопоточное, которое в принципе для основного потока может делать вид, что оно асинхронное

Comment: В принципе можно просто запустить архивацию в отдельном потоке через какой-нибудь run_in_executor. А так да, делать настоящую асинхронную библиотеку довольно бессмысленно